# Cómo finalizar un Script desde HTML en Google App Script?

Tags: html

Tengo una herramienta que realiza cierta tarea que no viene al caso. La herramienta funciona bien pero me gustaría poder terminarla manualmente mediante un botón en el HTML. El botón está creado, llama una función que se encuentra en el HTML y a su vez una función que se encuentra en el .gs, el problema es que no sé que código usar para finalizar el script, intenté buscar por todos lados, documentación de Google, aquí, en otras webs, y no lo puedo encontrar, desde ya agradezco su tiempo.

HTML

```
<script>
        function sample() { 
   
   var btnPlay = document.getElementById("boton");
     btnPlay.style.visibility = "hidden";
   var spin = document.getElementById("loadspin");
     spin.style.visibility = "visible";
    var btnDetener = document.getElementById("botonStop");
     btnDetener.style.visibility = "visible";
   
   var sourceFolderID = document.getElementById("docID").value;

   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandler).countSentences(sourceFolderID);

  }
    </script>

    <script>
        function successHandler(){
      
      var spin = document.getElementById("loadspin");
      spin.style.visibility = "hidden";
      var btnPlay = document.getElementById("boton");
      btnPlay.style.visibility = "visible";
      window.alert('Counting finished, please check your Google Drive');      
    }
    </script>

  <script>
    function stop() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(stopped).stopScript();
  }

  function stopped() {
    
    window.alert('Counting Stopped');
  }
    </script>
</head>
```

Este es el Script

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate();
}


function countSentences(sourceFolderID) {
  
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderID); // get desired folder which contains the documents
  var contents = sourceFolder.getFiles(); // get the documents.
  //var outFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(outFolderID); // folder where report is gonna be created
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Sentences Count"); // create SpreadSheet
  var file;
  var cnt = 0;
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Number of sentences", "Bootcamp Number", "Coach"]);

  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    cnt++;
    var documentID = file.getId();
    var document = DocumentApp.openById(documentID);
    var body = document.getBody();
    var contador = 0;

    for (var p = 4; p < body.getParagraphs().length; p++) {
      var text = body.getParagraphs()[p].getText();            
      var bootcampNumber = body.getParagraphs()[2].getText(); // extract paragraph with Bootcamp number and Coach
      var bootcampNum = bootcampNumber.substr(10,3);
      var coachName = bootcampNumber.substr(14,9);
      if (text.substr(0, 10) == "MXU Number") {
        break;
      } else {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
          var senNumber = j + "-";
          var senNumberD = j + ".";
          if (text.includes(senNumber) || text.includes(senNumberD)) {
            contador++;            
          }
        }
      }
    }
    data = [file.getName(), contador,bootcampNum,coachName];
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  };
  } 
  

function stopScript() {
  // acá es donde no sé que hacer
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refires con *finalizar el script*? ¿Cuál es el problema o error y dónde?

Comment: Me refiero a poder finalizar o terminar la ejecución del script con un botón desde el html, lo puedo hacer manualmente yendo a la opción que dice "mis ejecuciones" , pero no es así como quiero hacerlo, quiero que se haga con un botón.